# How do I make a custom Firefox build that contains customizations?

Tags: firefox, computer-building

Is there any app that can do this?

I would like to include in single Firefox install file

- addons
- user-styles
- user-scripts
- themes
- custom layout

I know I could just use [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109) and restore it, but it would be nice to have single step install to have it all, to build it for friends and family that don't know much about addons and stuff.

If not an app, can it be done manually?

Answer (score 1):

There's command line options for installing an extension and a theme:

```
firefox.exe -install-global-extension "C:\Temp\extension-file.xpi"
firefox.exe -install-global-theme /path/to/theme
```

*[Command Line Arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Command_Line_Options)*

I'm wondering if this could be done by downloading the extensions, compiling them into a folder and create a batch file to install them.

As for:

> - user-styles
> - user-scripts
> - themes
> - custom layout

You may be able to copy over some files from your own Firefox profile and simply copy them to the user's profile, again in the batch file. Not sure how well this would work (there might be index files for scripts for example) but it's certainly worth investigating.